# iphone: Confusion with Push Notification provisioning profile and AdHoc Profile

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I have implemented UrbanAirship Push notification in my app.

But I am little bit confuse while creating AdHoc.

I have made provisioning profile for Debug in which I am selecting Device IDs.

So while creating AdHoc, Do I need to create new AdHoc profile or Its not needed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the provisional profile is not the thing related to push notification settings. But you need to configure your appID under the apple developers account section and select it for push notification enabled. Under that appID you can use developers provisional profile or distribution provisional profile easily. No confusion any more.

Try this. And let me know.

Comment: Nice !! I have made new developers provisional profile. but do I need to make distribution provisional profile for Adhoc ? Or I can Use developers provisional profile for AdHoc creation ?

Comment: You can use the developer provisional profile for adHoc creation. Even it is better that you can debug in the device too. So, Go with the developer provisional profile is also a good option.

Comment: Is it safe to use developer provisional profile for AdHoc ? And Yes I am using developer provisional for debug. but confuse with AdHoc profile.

Comment: Hello Devang. No need to confuse here. You can send the release app using developer provisional profile without any problem. It's the same thing that you can do with the distribution. Only the difference is that by distribution profile you can't debug on device. I also done with the push notification and send the adHoc release to client using developer provisional profile and it is totally safe.

Comment: Thanks. Let me know if you have any more questions. Will like to answer all.

Comment: Hey, As per our talk I have used Developers Provisional Profile for AdHoc. But it is giving me Entitlements Error.

Comment: Have you added Entitlements.plist in your project or no. If you are using XCode 4 or later then no need to add Entitlements.plist

Comment: plz dont mind for joining the discussion. what is push notification regarding distribution/developer profile.i knew both profiles but no knowledge abt push notification in this scenario. plz reply

Comment: Push notification is the notification service provided by apple for notify some event happened on server side. It is the special notification which alerts even when the application is not running. Youc can find more detail on the following link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a distribution certificate. Then in the provisioning section select distribution and then create a new provisioning profile select ad-hoc there.

Comment: I am confuse with Push Notifications provisioning profile and AdHoc profile. I have made new provisioning profile and push notification works well with it. But do I need to change anything for AdHoc ?

Comment: You need to create a new provisioning profile for ad hoc distribution and enable push notification for that profile.