# iPhone : Getting problem as "Entitlements Does not match"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, entitlements

I am getting error as "Entitlements does not match".

Here I am using developers provisioning profile for AdHoc building.

This developers provisioning profile is enabled with Push Notification(UrbanAirship).

I have discuss about the profile selection [Here is Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690871/iphone-confusion-with-push-notification-provisioning-profile-and-adhoc-profile) but that is giving me above error.

Am I doing something wrong ? As I am using developers provisioning profile(Debugging profile) for AdHoc building.

Or what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use distribution provisioning profile for ad-hoc build.